# Создать собственный вариант TileMode c# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Можно как-то создать собственный вариант ImageDrawing.TileMode в c# wpf.

Нужно cмещение на пол картинки:

[image: Смещение на пол картинки]

Comment: Не думаю что нужно изобретать велосипед, посмотрите на [ImageBrush](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.media.imagebrush(v=vs.110).aspx) и как пример другой вопрос про смещение [offset](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479764/can-you-render-using-a-visualbrush-that-has-an-offset). Может что-то из этого поможет.

Comment: @Shakra, стандартными средствами такое проделать не удается.